# WooCommerce - Ordering related products by sales custom calculation

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields, product

Woocommerce related products template is located on:

```
/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/related.php
```

But it currently order by **random**.

I would like to order that by **`'total_sales' + 'sales_count'`** (those are 2 meta_keys hold integer values and **`'sales_count'`** is an additional **custom** field).

Here is the query:

```
 $args = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_related_products_args', array(
    'post_type'            => 'product',
    'ignore_sticky_posts'  => 1,
    'no_found_rows'        => 1,
    'posts_per_page'       => 4,
    'orderby'   => 'total_sales',
     'order' => 'DESC',
    'post__in'             => $related
) );
    $products = new WP_Query( $args );
```

The above query sort products buy **total_sales** but I need to sort that using sum of **total_sales** and **sales_count**?

Is there a way to do this?.

Thanks

Comment: sorry i added some more info it just need order by sum of two custom fields the other parameters are  normal

Comment: total_sales value increment by wocommerce when customers place orders which also has as a custom field, 
sales_count custom field added by me which also hold some integer number, the usage of sales_count is we use that for display on product pages sales_count+total_sales . so a product doesn't have any actual sales before, the product shows some sales using  sales_count field

Comment: $units_sold = get_post_meta( $product->id, 'total_sales', true );
$soldty=  get_post_meta( $product->id, 'sales_count', true );

echo 'Sales: '.($units_sold+$soldty);

Comment: so we need to order related products $units_sold+$soldty, we curently sort that using total_sales

Comment: no just using WordPress custom fields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I doesn't understand very well the purpose of **`$soldty = get_post_meta( $product->id, 'sales_count', true );`**, as default **`'total_sales'`** for a product makes already the calculation of all items sold (the item quantity sold is added each time to the count).*

Anyway, If you really need this calculation, the best option will be to make a function that will create/update a new custom field, for each product,  with that calculation:

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'products_update_total_sales_calculation' );
function products_update_total_sales_calculation(){
    $sales = array();
    $all_products = get_posts( array(
        'post_type'            => 'product',
        'post_status'          => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page'       => -1,
    ) );
    foreach($all_products as $item) {
        $units_sold = get_post_meta( $item->ID, 'total_sales', true );
        $soldty = get_post_meta( $item->ID, 'sales_count', true );
        if(empty($soldty)) $soldty = 0;
        $result = $units_sold + $soldty;
        update_post_meta( $item->ID, 'global_sales_count', $result );
    }
}
```

This function make the calculation for product sales and create/update a custom field **`'global_sales_count'`** with the calculation value in it.

Now you can customized your query **`'orderby'`** argument based on this new custom field:

```
$args = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_related_products_args', array(
    'post_type'            => 'product',
    'ignore_sticky_posts'  => 1,
    'no_found_rows'        => 1,
    'posts_per_page'       => 4,
    'meta_key'             => 'global_sales_count', // <== <== the new custom field
    'orderby'              => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'                => 'DESC',
    'post__in'             => $related

) );
    $products = new WP_Query( $args );
```

---

If you don't need your calculation, the `'meta_key'` value will be changed to existing **`'total_sales'`** product **`meta_key`**, this way:

```
$args = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_related_products_args', array(
    'post_type'            => 'product',
    'ignore_sticky_posts'  => 1,
    'no_found_rows'        => 1,
    'posts_per_page'       => 4,
    'meta_key'             => 'total_sales', // <== <== the existing meta_key 
    'orderby'              => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'                => 'DESC',
    'post__in'             => $related

) );
    $products = new WP_Query( $args );
```